# Send param to fetch in getInitialProps react and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I 'm traying to send a param to getInitialProp function to made the fecth to the correct json.

here is my code:
hepler.js -->  here I made the fetch per se.

```
export async function getEvents() {
  const res = await fetch("https://url/eventos.json");
  let new_data = await res.json();

  return { events: new_data.data };
}

export async function getDetails(slug) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://myurl/${slug}.json`);
  let data_detail_event = await res.json();
  return { data_detail_event };
}
```

_app.js // here I have the getInitialProps and works great

```
import App from "next/app";
import ContextProvider from "../provider/ContextProvider";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
import {getEvents, getDetails} from '../helper/index'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps() {

    const events = await getEvents();
    return {
      events : events.events
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ContextProvider events={this.props.events} >
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ContextProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

pages/[id].js

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Context from "../../config/Context";
/* Components */
import WordCounter from "../../components/word-counter/WordCounter";

function Post(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const context = React.useContext(Context);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <WordCounter />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
Post.getInitialProps = async ({ query}) => {
  const detail = await getDetail(query.id) --> here I send the param and it seems never arrive to helper.js, why?
  return {detail}
}
export default  Post
```

Where is the problem? HELP!
THAANKS!

Comment: what do  you get if you do  `console.log(slug)` in `getDetails` ?

Comment: Hi Nico.. I m getting nothing...

Comment: I can make it work if a create a function inside Post, like this:  ` const data = async () => {
    const detail = await getDetails(router.query.id)
    console.log(detail)
    return {detail}
  } 
  data();` but I dont think is the best way..

Answer (score 0):

i think getInitialProps run in server and your helper function doesn't load there.

use fetch inside getInitialProps .